# How to declare an instance of another class?

Tags: c#, class, methods, instance

I have following question, right now like 2 minutes ago a guy posted his code.

He couldn't use his instance `obj` , and I don't know why he deleted his question.

He had also some usings, I think he had `using static N.Form1`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        int Y(int a)
        {
            a = 10;
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            return a;
        }
        }  
    }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Class1
    {
       N.Form1 obj = new N.Form1();
        public void X(int a)
        {
            var v = obj.Y(a);
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
    }
}
```

So first I've seperate the method, and made it public so I can create instance and use it in another class.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public int Y(int a)
        {
            a = 10;
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            return a;
        }
    }
```

And then instead of using `N.From1`, I used the namespace for declaring instance `WindowsFormsApp1.Form1 obj = new WindowsFormsApp1.Form1();`

My Class1 looks like this now:

```
 class Class1
    {
        WindowsFormsApp1.Form1 obj = new WindowsFormsApp1.Form1();
        public void X(int a)
        {
            var v = obj.Y(a);
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
    }
```

So there isn't any error, and my question is, is this the right way to declare and instance and use it later? Also are you allowed to use the namespace ?

Thanks,

Comment: Of course you can also specify a class by it's fully qualified namespace. But it is not necessary here because both classes are in the same namespace.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Could you suggest me better option please ?

Comment: @MariaB.what he is saying is that you could just do something like `Form1 obj = new Form1()` as your Class1 and Form1 are in the same namespace WindowsFormsApp1

Comment: @TimSchmelter yeaaahh, you can use the constructor, thank you very much.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for the info. I appreciate it =)